Incorporating Power Amplifier Specifications into a Link Budget Calculation for VHF Communication with a CubeSat
I am in the process of creating a link budget for communication between a ground station equipped with a VHF antenna and a CubeSat. To do this, I plan to use the Friis transmission formula. The VHF antenna at the ground station has a gain of 12.7 dBi and delivers a maximum power of 2 × 1500 watts due to circular polarization. On the other hand, the CubeSat's antenna has a maximum output power of 2 watts and a gain of 1.5 dBi.
The free-space path loss for a 600 km orbit of the CubeSat at a frequency of 144 MHz is approximately 131.18 dB (assuming this value is correct).
If I want to buy a power amplifier with harmonic rejection, should I consider the power delivered and gain of the power amplifier in the link budget? For instance, if the power amplifier has an output power of 70 watts and a gain of 36 dBi, should these parameters be included in the link budget calculations?

You need to consider the back-off from compression for the power amplifier used, which will depend on the waveform peak-avg ratio (crest factor) and specified requirements for waveform quality at the transmitter output and out-of-band emissions (usually part of the minimum performance requirements for the transmitter design itself as well as any regulatory requirements). This will lead to a power amplifier efficiency which can also factor in implementation design details to improve this specifically such as crest-factor-reduction and waveform predistortion. These factors can have a significant impact on the realizable efficiency (DC power required to achieve a specified transmit power level) and the overall size and cost of the power amplifier itself. The power amplifier can often be a significant portion of the overall power dissipation budget so much effort is placed in the design effort in maximizing PA efficiency for power sensitive designs, and often drives the consideration as to what waveform is used in the design. Multi-channel waveforms will have significantly high peak-avg ratios due to the central limit theorem even if the individual waveforms themselves were constant-envelope (the distribution of the sum of independent waveforms will approach a Gaussian), so that also becomes part of the considerations.
Ultimately for the link budget you will have a Tx Power specified, but what power amplifier you buy will depend on the above considerations. If the Power Amplifier is capable of 70W, this may be the saturated output power. If a 10 dB back-off was required to meet the waveform quality and out-of-band emission requirements (which is not unheard of), then this means that same PA will only transmit 7W (and meanwhile the DC power required to bias the amplifier may be minimally reduced, meaning the PA efficiency goes down significantly as we increase the back-off from PA saturation.)  To be able to proceed with a link budget, I typically identify a candidate PA and have a starting value for back-off from saturation that would be needed (which is completely waveform and application dependent). The completion of the first link budget and overall power dissipation then drives the amount of further design details that may be needed in researching alternate solutions specific to the PA that was initially chosen, but a starting point is necessary (if there is no such information and a quick back-of the napkin calculation is needed, I recommend using 15% efficiency as a starting value, or higher if it is certain that the waveform itself is constant envelope or very low peak-avg ratio).
